# Find index of Custom List - Kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, arraylist

I have a list

```
val SongList = [SongInfo(name="Dark Star", rawId="2131689475", time=1:30), SongInfo(name="Can't let go", rawId="2131689474", time=1:24), , SongInfo(name="Big Digits", rawId="2131689473", time=0:49), SongInfo(name="What's Mine", rawId=2131689478]
```

and to get the song name I do this

```
val song = songList[0].name
```

shuffling song

```
songList.shuffle()
```

how do I find an index of song, after shuffling the list?

Comment: So if a song gets shuffled from index 0 to index 2, you want to get 0, not 2?

Comment: I want the index after shuffle so it is 2. Someone gave a correct answered and deleted it.

Comment: The *shuffle* method doesn't exist for lists but arrays. Instead for lists there are the *shuffled* method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code isn't the best solution but it finds the index, and return the song name by index.

```kotlin
data class SongInfo(var name: String, var rawId: String, var time: String)

fun main() {
    val songList = listOf(
        SongInfo(name = "Dark Star", rawId = "2131689475", time = "1:30"),
        SongInfo(name = "Can't let go", rawId = "2131689474", time = "1:24"),
        SongInfo(name = "Big Digits", rawId = "2131689473", time = "0:49"),
        SongInfo(name = "What's Mine", rawId = "2131689478", time = "22:31")
    )
    val song = songList[0].name
    val shuffledSongList = songList.shuffled()
    println(shuffledSongList)
    var index = 0
    while (true) {
        if (shuffledSongList[index].name == song) break
        index++
    }
    println(shuffledSongList[index].name)
}
```